# "B&W" or "B/W"?

Tags: word-choice, abbreviations

I've seen both *B/W* and *B&W* used to describe *black and white*.  Is one accepted over the other?  If regional, then what would I use in AmE?

Comment: I'd say they're both perfectly acceptable in AmE.

Comment: Such abbreviations are frequently used in 'product descriptions'. Such as **A/C** for *air-conditioning*, **H/C** for *hot-and-cold*, etc. These were (and still are) very often hand-written, where people avoid the ampersand because it's awkward and may easily be mis-read. I think the ampersand is a Johnny-come-lately that's gaining currency because computers tend to be a bit unpredictable about how they handle the slash character (as RegDwight points out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be slightly odd if there were an 'industry standard' for this one. Even odder if the general speaking / writing public both knew of that standard and actually used it.

As noted in a comment against OP, you can't check this one with Ngrams because that doesn't support the slash character in search terms.

But you *can* Google for

**"b/w" movies**
which reports 6,650,000 hits, and

**"b&w" movies**
which reports 4,570,000.

If I add the word **american** I get 2,960,000 as against 2,310,000. That's much the same ratio, which may imply there're no particular tendency for Americans to favour one term over the other.

I can't restrict Google to US sites only, but I can restrict it to UK only. That gives *twice* as many hits for **b/w**, which may suggest that we Brits prefer the slash form. I know I do.

Answer (score 0):

I guess in different regions/dialects people use either the phrase "**Black and White**" or "**Black or White**". So possibly, as derivative of each of these, we have B&W and B/W.

Comment: I don't think anybody ever says **Black or White** when talking about a monochrome tv.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't see anything about TV in the question or the answer ...

Comment: @Matthew Read: I hope I'm always ready to be educated. It needn't be a tv. Do you know of any dialect where people say **Black or White** in a context where the rest of us say **Black and White**? As at the time of writing, I certainly don't.

Comment: I think some would contrast *black **or** white* with *shades of gray*, but I was referring to the abbreviation of *black **and** white* as opposed to *color*

Comment: @snumpy: As I understood from the question, since so far as I know B/W and B&W are only ever used in the sense of 'monochrome' (i.e. - not colour). I was simply making the point that **B/W** can't be interpreted as shorthand for **Black OR White** in any context I know of.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "any dialect where people say Black or White..." Heard of the MJ song?? "Black or White" ?

Comment: @Codevalley: I'm not saying **Black or White** doesn't occur. Of course it does. My point was that it would be unusual to use the '**or**' form in a context where most of us use '**and**'. But I now see that about 1/3 of all Google references to the **Black and White fallacy** use '**or**', so I guess I should concede now!

Answer (score 0):

They are both valid, since they are abbreviations and no industry standard has been established for cinematography, photography, print media, or other visual medium industry.

Comment: By "industry" are you referring to televisions, video, etc?

Comment: Ah, thank you. I had the photography industry in mind, when writing, but you make a good point, sir.

Comment: True, they are both valid. But that would be the case whether or not one of them happened to be an 'industry standard'. In the music performing / recording industry, the standard term for all circular connectors (like the one that goes from your iPod to your earphones) is a *jack*. But outside the industry it's normally called a *plug*.

Comment: I always called them jacks. :/  So, you're suggesting that standards are not always followed.  Generally Accepted Accounting Principles (GAAP) are an example of a standard that are religiously followed by all financial professionals. We're talking about everyday Joes, so it really could go either way.